# controlling movement of image in iphone game

Tags: objective-c

i have one code which moves the uiimage  on touch-event

it's like this:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches]anyObject];
touchOffset= image.center.x-[touch locationInView:touch.view].x;
}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches]anyObject];
//paddle movemant coordinates
float distanceMoved=([touch locationInView:touch.view].x+touchOffset)- image.center.x;
float newX= image.center.x+distanceMoved;
if(newX>30 &&newX<290)
image.center=CGPointMake(newX, image.center.y);
if(newX>290)
image.center=CGPointMake(290, image.center.y);
if(newX<30)
image.center=CGPointMake(30,  image.center.y);
}
```

BUT the problem is that I want this action must be perform on button(left-right button)action.When ever I pressed the left button   UIImage move little bit  to left side. And  When ever I pressed the Right  button   UIImage move little bit  to right  side basically I want image movement controller with button only on x axis of iphone or pad.

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You have UIImages that you have detecting touches and you're using these images as buttons, right? Why not use UIButtons and you embed the images in the button? This way, whenever the button gets clicked, you can intercept the button instance that performed the click.

Comment: didn't get you dear.help me friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGRect frame = [image frame]; frame.origin.x += 10.0f; [image setFrame:frame]; 
use this & map your buton actions with it .

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect frame = [image frame];
frame.origin.x += 10.0f;
[image setFrame:frame];
```

Comment: it work but i want to move object left to right & right to left with help joypad in game.